# Error While Creating A Web-Service That Contains A Method Return An ArrayList Type

Tags: asp.net, web-services, arraylist

I've Create A Web-Service Seems Like

```
Public Class NameAndvalue
    Public name As String
    Public value As String
End Class
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function ReturnNames_1() As ArrayList
    Dim names As New List(Of NameAndvalue)
    Dim nv As NameAndvalue
    nv = New NameAndvalue With {.name = "AAA", .value = "1"} : names.Add(nv)
    nv = New NameAndvalue With {.name = "BBB", .value = "2"} : names.Add(nv)
    nv = New NameAndvalue With {.name = "CCC", .value = "3"} : names.Add(nv)
    Dim Arr As ArrayList = New ArrayList(names)
    Return Arr
End Function
```

When I Invoke In The Browser (Give ME An Error ... )

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the
>   XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type
>   TMR.AndroidMethods+NameAndvalue was not expected. Use the XmlInclude
>   or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known
>   statically.    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteTypedPrimitive(String
>   name, String ns, Object o, Boolean xsiType)    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write1_Object(String
>   n, String ns, Object o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write2_ArrayOfAnyType(Object
>   o)    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayListSerializer.Serialize(Object
>   objectToSerialize, XmlSerializationWriter writer)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter,
>   Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle,
>   String id)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter,
>   Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle,
>   String id)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter
>   textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.XmlReturnWriter.Write(HttpResponse
>   response, Stream outputStream, Object returnValue)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.WriteReturns(Object[]
>   returnValues, Stream outputStream)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.WriteReturns(Object[]
>   returnValues)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()

With Knowledge That This Error I Saw it When I was return an `list(of string)` from Method
because of that i change the return from the `List(Of String)` To `ArrayList` But The Same Problem occurred.

What Is The Problem ??

Answer (score 1):

Try using `List(Of NameAndvalue)` instead. The following example

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function HelloWorld() As List(Of NameAndvalue)
    Dim names As New List(Of NameAndvalue)
    Dim nv As NameAndvalue
    nv = New NameAndvalue With {.name = "AAA", .value = "1"} : names.Add(nv)
    nv = New NameAndvalue With {.name = "BBB", .value = "2"} : names.Add(nv)
    nv = New NameAndvalue With {.name = "CCC", .value = "3"} : names.Add(nv)

    Return names
End Function
```

returns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfNameAndvalue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <NameAndvalue>
    <name>AAA</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </NameAndvalue>
  <NameAndvalue>
    <name>BBB</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </NameAndvalue>
  <NameAndvalue>
    <name>CCC</name>
    <value>3</value>
  </NameAndvalue>
</ArrayOfNameAndvalue>
```

Comment: Thanks , But Do You Know How Can I Receive This `List(OF ...)`
From the Android For Example ?
Or From VB.NET Application ?

Comment: `List(OF...)` get serialized as an array of object `NameAndValue`. I don't have a means of testing it from Java, but from VB.NET the necessary code will generated when you add a service reference in your project. Then your call will look something like this `Dim names() = svc.HelloWorld()`, where names would be an array of `NameAndValue` objects.